# Create Web API without Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I was wondering if is it possible to create a Web API without Entity Framework.

This should be strange but supposing to have this table

`T_BOOKS`:

```
BookId int
BookTitle nvarchar(50)
```

and a stored procedure that returns me something like that

```
select BookId, BookTitle 
from T_BOOKS
```

Then I add a column to both the table and the stored procedure

`T_BOOKS`:

```
BookId int
BookTitle nvarchar(50)
BookAuthor nvarchar(50)

select BookId, BookTitle, BookAuthor 
from T_BOOKS
```

Why should I change the controller and redeploy entire WebAPI ?

Any answer is appreciated.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebAPI and Entity Framework are two different technologies. One is a framework to provide easy to create HTTP services while other is a Framework for data access.

You, of course, can provide data to a Web API with any data provider you like. Entity Framework is a choice while, ADO.NET, NHibernate and other technologies may be other choices.

Answer (score 2):

Entity Framework is not necessary for Web API. You can retrieve and return the data using any method you prefer.